# Using Rxjs umd bundles

Tags: angular, rxjs

I just took a leap from angular QuickStart for 2.0.0-rc2 and updated system-config.ts file to download umd file for rxjs I.e `rxjs\bundles\Rx.umd.js`

This worked. But I still see in dev tools a lot of individual JS being load like `rxjs\observer.js`

I see http.umd.js from @angular reference it directly via

```
import {Observer} from 'rxjs\observer
```

Is there any way to just load single Rx.umd.js or we have to live with unbundled files as well.

Ps: my dist folder has non bundled rxjs file as well because I am in middle of switching to umd.js which I will correct later.

Comment: This will be fixe in @angular 2.0.0-rc4 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359

Comment: Still not fixed in rc.4. Supposedly on roadmap for rc.5

Comment: Still seeing the same in rc6 :(

Comment: If you took a leap from Angular QuickStart I suggest you take another to angular CLI which will manage the compilation while developing the app

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to ship a small number of UMD or FESM bundles, one for each of the handful of imports (rxjs, rxjs/operators, etc.).

For example:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```